# iOS10 NotificationService Extension

Tags: ios10

The method:

didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler:(UNNotificationContent) -> Void)

of iOS 10's NotificationService TARGET is not triggered automatically by iOS, even if the payload of my remote notification contains the attribute: "mutable-content" : 1.

Here you are the payload example:

```
    {
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "body": "body",
      "subtitle": "subtitle",
      "title": "title"
    },
    "mutable-content": 1
  }
}
```

Is there any missing configuration or code do I have to implement in order to make it works ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should run the application with the extension as a target, and choose the app you would like the extension to work with. Typically you will run the extension on the application in the containing project.

[image: Run the extension.]

After running the Extension target, your app will load, and when you will send notifications with "mutable-content : 1", you will be able to step in debug mode.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question – it only tells how to get into debug mode. And, if, you get that working then it should work in the real app. I.e. it seems that it should work when the app is downloaded from the App Store.

Comment: @StackUnderflow This does answer the questions since it provides the means for 'making it work'.

Comment: Running the extension instead of the app is definitely the key! Thanks for pointing that out.